# How to serialize generic relations in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an Administrator model associated with three other models through generic relationship.

```
A = 'Active'
    D = 'Disabled'
    status = (
        (A, 'Active'),
        (D, 'Disabled')
    )

    limit_choices = (models.Q(app_label='core', model='track') | models.Q(app_label='core',
                    model='company') | models.Q(app_label='core', model='member') )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=limit_choices, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=status, default=D)

class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)



class Company(models.Model):
    partner_id = models.ForeignKey(Track, related_name='companies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)


class Member(models.Model):
    carrier_id = models.ForeignKey(Track,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

For serialization, I use the sample [code](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships) from the official documentation.

**serializer.py**

```
class AdministratorSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'status', )
        model = Administrator

    def to_representation(self, value):

        if isinstance(value, Track):
            return value.id
        elif isinstance(value, Member):
            return value.id
        elif isinstance(value, Company):
            return value.id
        raise Exception('Unexpected type of tagged object')
```

But I got an error

```
TypeError at /administrator/
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Please help me to solve this task/

Comment: `serializers.RelatedField` should be use for field not for the model serializer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DRF docs says, Create a generic serializer field (here, `GenericField`) and wire-up in your Serializer class (here, `AdministratorSerializer` ).

```
class GenericField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):

        if isinstance(value, Track):
            return value.id
        elif isinstance(value, Member):
            return value.id
        elif isinstance(value, Company):
            return value.id
        raise Exception('Unexpected type of tagged object')


class AdministratorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    generic_data = GenericField(source='content_object', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'status', 'generic_data')
        model = Administrator
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I think this is exactly what I need. But now I get the message `AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.`

Comment: provide **`read_only=True`** in `GenericField`. Check my updated answer @Jekson

Comment: yes its work. Could you tell me if I can get what I would get not only the id, but also a link to the associated model? I try to change the ModelSerializer to
 HyperlinkedModelSerializer but this does not change the result.

Comment: Oh..that's seems a different question mate. You should ask a new one :)